# How do you get the division sign using the ALT codes?

Tags: alt

I cannot find the ALT code for the division sign.

Answer (score 2):

Alt+0247 will make the ÷/Obelus/Division sign

Comment: It would be worth mentioning that this is also font dependent.  While the vast majority of fonts do indeed have this symbol a few may not. A quick glance through my system shows at least a couple of fonts (such as "MS Outlook") are missing this character and at least one other shows this as a "play" icon.